# Insertar una consola de javascript en el navegador

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un playground de javascript y quiero colocar una consola como la de google chrome para que no haya necesidad de abrir la que ya trae el navegador.

Encontré esta alternativa pero no funciona: [chromeConsole](https://github.com/TarVK/chromeConsole)

Funciona con jquery pero al intertar usarla aparece este error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).console is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (78633768-db82-40c6-9dd4-83a7e8b845e2:31:42)
at mightThrow (jquery.js:3583:29)
at process (jquery.js:3651:12)
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cargar los ficheros JS localmente? Los enlaces que ofrece en su demo no terminan de funcionar porque se sirven con un MimeType incorrecto

Comment: ya lo probe y muestra errores con respecto a ace (ya que utiliza ace editor por debajo)